# group of elements height , children and parents

Tags: html, css

I am considering about something, maybe its pointless but thanks for an answer anyway.

example:

html:

```css
nav {
  background: white;
  <!-- border-bottom: solid gray 1px; -->
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;             /* NAV Height*/
}
.nav-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 3em;
  margin: auto 3em auto 0;
}
.nav-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: inherit;
}
.nav-menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 55px;       /* NAV Height*/
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation"> 
     <div class="nav-menu"> 
   <ul> 
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">next</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">previous</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">before</a></li> 
   </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

I was thinking, that to change my 'nav' height I only need to change the nested 'li' element hight, but it comes out that its not enough.

Is something wrong in this code? Thanks for comments.

Comment: What is your expected result? I cannot understand very well what is your question.

Comment: you'll have to change `nav` height value and also `li` line-height

Comment: for example, if you made just a <div><div>,  and you insert some content inside, the div area will stretch to the content size. Yes?  
So, my question is: why the <nav></nav> doesn't stretch to the content hight? In my example the <li> height ?

Comment: in that case it would be because your `<div class="nav-menu">` has a `float: right;` style. you can use another DIV after you close that one with style `clear: both;` to clear the float.

Comment: ok, I get it.  thxs

Comment: Is the 'float: right' style, to have links on one side of the nav the good solution in Your opinion?